# Is there a way to find out which PHP pages are taking more resources in a linux server?

Tags: php, linux, apache

My linux server websites keep going down again and again but SSH, FTP, etc are alive. So I had a look at the server through SSH and used top command which lists all the processes. It shows that when some PHP pages are executed, mysql CPU usage reaches 100%. So is there any command/log which can be used to find out which PHP pages are taking up so much of mysql usage? Thank you...

Comment: which pages are doing complicated things with mysql? did you take a look at mysql slow query log?

Comment: This kind of analysis is called `Profiling`. If you google 'PHP Profiling' you'll find a few tools that can do this. I have no experience with using these but maybe it helps your search a bit.

Comment: oh... is there something like that? That will be a great place to find out the problem. Can you please let me know usually where it is found please? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If MySQL is getting stuck at 100% then you've probably got some badly tuned MySQL queries inside one of your PHP applications. This time will clock up in the MySQL daemon and so won't show up in the %D value. This could be indexes out of date.

If you have access to the D/B through at the command prompt through SSH then you could try doing an ANALYZE TABLE and OPTIMIZE TABLE on any large tables.  Also look at "The Slow Query Log" in the MySQL documentation.

Unfortunately fixing this will probably need you to get into the Application internals.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at your Apache log format to see if it includes the %D parameter as this indicates the amount of time taken to to serve a request in microseconds.

If you exclude anything but requests to PHP scripts, you should get an idea of which scripts are taking the longest suggesting high execution time. Obviously this could also mean a very large response payload...

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple aspects to resource consumption.

As mobius mentioned, you can use SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST in MySQL to see what is currently running. Look at the processed taking longer than you would expect and check out the query to find hints about where it originates in your application.

The problem may not be with the application. It might simply be a matter of tuning MySQL, which will be about adding or changing indexes most of the time. EXPLAIN is the command that will you help analyze the execution plan MySQL decided to use. Reading EXPLAIN takes some practice. The best reference I have is [High Performance MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101716).

You can also use the MySQL slow query log to get information about the slow queries happening when you are not in front of the server.

If MySQL is running at 100%, you will probably find the problem from there. If you really want to track the usage from PHP, you can set up [XHProf](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof), a high performance profiler created by Facebook to run on production sites. You can set it up to sample one request out of 100 and get a bigger picture of the performance of your site. There are a few articles out there that explain how to set it up.

Finally, XDebug and KCacheGrind can be used in development to profile one request at a time.

Answer (score 0):

mytop - http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/ (SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST on your mySQL)
Xdebug Profiler - http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler